# How to schedule Kibana index rollover?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat, kibana-7

From Kibana below ILM policy is applied:

```
PUT _ilm/policy/filebeat
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "1d"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "4d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With above policy, if index is created at today 11am then new index is creating tomorrow 11am but my expectation is new index should create every day at 12am, as I want 1 index per day.

Any idea how can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Create index templates and suffix your indices with a day, e.g. `my-logs-2020.10.14`, indices will be created automatically with template settings.

Comment: I already having date as suffix like this filebeat-7.7.0-2020.10.13-000072     but the name of index has nothing to do with data inside it. I mean filebeat-7.7.0-2020.10.13-000072 index say created at 2pm today then a new index with 14th october date suffix create at 2pm tomorrow again. that mean 13th october suffixed index  holding 12am to 2pm data of 14th. agree? as per policy i pasted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana we have an option called rollup job to achieve same: https://www.elastic.co/webinars/managing-your-elasticsearch-data-lifecycle
[image]